# How to open URL in same window using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

```
<form id="search" action="">
            <input id="findroom" type="text" class="defaultText" title="Room Name">
            <input id="find" type="submit" value="Find">
        </form>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#search').submit(function() {
                var r = "/rooms/"+$('#findroom').val();
                open(r);
              });
            });
        </script>
```

Having trouble with the code above. I am trying to generate a restful URL for use in a Ruby on Rails app. I can generate the URL I need from the form as the var 'r'. When I use open() as above the link opens fine, but in a new window. I need it to open in the same window. Have tried:

```
open.(r,'_self');
```

doesn't work

haven't had any luck with:

```
location.replace
location.href =
```

Anybody have any ideas please?

Thanks

Barry

Answer (score 5):

It's as simple as

```
window.location = r;
```

Answer (score 2):

To open a new popup, use

```
window.open(r);
```

If you want to redirect the current page, use

```
window.location = r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

You just need to give _self in name

[Please read more](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Answer (score 0):

[window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) creates a new secondary browser window and loads the referenced resource, whereas [windo.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) allows for changing the URL of the current window. So what you want is:

```
window.location = r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. You're all on the money, *but* the answer is

```
e.preventDefault();
```

It's to do with the form submitting and overriding the window.location command. Once you block the default behaviour it works. This is the full code:

```
<section id="roomsearch">
        <form id="search" action="">
            <input id="findroom" type="text" class="defaultText" title="Room Name">
            <input id="find" type="submit" value="Find">
        </form>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#search').submit(function(e) {
                var r = "/rooms/"+$('#findroom').val();
                window.location = r;
                e.preventDefault();         
              });
            });
        </script>


    </section>
```

Thanks for the time and help.

Barry